# Why is my text in the jTextarea not highlighted anymore?

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea

I am making a small Swing application and have a JTextarea where I want a part of the text to be highlighted.

When I start my appl. the line that I indicated to be highlighted is highlighted by the method "highlight()"

```
    public static void highlight() {
    uihw.getTa().setSelectionStart(indexTxt[pencil]);//uihw is the ui instvar that has the jTextarea
    uihw.getTa().setSelectionEnd(indexTxt[pencil]+lines[pencil].length());
}
```

As seen here: [image]

Now, the moment I hit a Button ,it should select the next item below and highlight it.

```
    public static void buttonClicked(String f){
    if (pencil!=lines.length-1){
        pencil++;
    }
    highlight();
}
```

And this is where the highlighting stops working.
I can go through the list up until the end (so I am sure the selection is actually done) but the text isn't highlighted anymore.

Any ideas on the why? Or suggestions for a better implementation of my highlighting feature?

Comment: 1) Just by the looks of it, won't a `JList` suit you better? 2) Do you want the highlight to just be visual or do you want a highlight that allows you to copy the highlighted section?

Comment: Just the visual part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selections may not be visible if the component loses focus. Instead you can use the Highlighter of the Component:

```
HighlightPainter highlightPainter = DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.BLUE);//
Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
highlighter.addHighlight(start, end, highlightPainter);
```

If you wish the color to be the same as a selection color, you can use

```
HighlightPainter highlightPainter = DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter;
```

or specify the selection color via the Look and feel

```
HighlightPainter highlightPainter = DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(UIManager.getColor("TextArea.selectionBackground"));
```

Comment: `If you wish the color to be the same as a selection color` - you can use the `DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter`, +1.

Comment: @camickr, excellent! The API is a little shy on defining exactly what the color of that object is.